Do (actual) homeomorphisms preserve closures of subspaces?
My question is

Do (actual) homeomorphisms preserve closures of subspaces?

There's another question

Do homeomorphisms preserve closures of subspaces?

Do homeomorphisms preserve closures of subspaces? ( I think duplicate of "closure preserves homeomorphism" )
But I think title is wrong because the ambient spaces aren't homeomorphic. In that question we have topological spaces $X$ & $Y$ which are unrelated except that they have respective subspaces $A, B$ that happen to be homeomorphic $f: A \to B$. Expectedly, the closures of $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily homeomorphic, just like $A=(0,1)$ and $X=Y=B=\mathbb R$.
This time, I want to know what happens if the homeomorphism $f$ comes from a homeomorphism between the ambient topological spaces:
Let $g: X \to Y$ be a homeomorphism. Suppose $g$'s restriction to $A$ gives a homeomorphism $f: A \to B$. Explicitly:

Restrict domain of $g$ to $A$ to get the map $g|_A : A \to Y, (g|_A)(x) := g(x)$.
Suppose $image(g)=g(A)=B$.
Now restrict range of $g|_A$ to $B$ to get the map $f:A \to B, f(x) = g(x)$.
Since $g$ is a homeomorphism, $g|_A$ and $f$ are injective.
Suppose $f$ is a homeomorphism too. (i.e. $g|_A$ is an embedding right?)

Hence, like in the previous question, we have a homeomorphism $f: A \to B$ between the subspaces $A$ & $B$. But now I'm additionally supposing this $f$ is a homeomorphism derived from a homeomorphism $g: X \to Y$ between the respective ambient topological spaces $X$ and $Y$.
If $g$ is not a homeomorphism, I don't see why $\text{closure}_X(A) = \text{closure}_Y(B)$. But now that $g$ is, maybe now $g(\text{closure}_X(A)) = \text{closure}_Y(B)$...
...Actually, apparently not. According to this Why are the closures of $(0,1)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ not homeomorphic despite the intervals themselves being homeomorphic?
$$A=(0,1), B=(0,\infty), X = Y = \mathbb R, \ \text{then whatever f & g you like}$$
Questions:

Ok so generally, when do (actual) homeomorphisms preserve closures of subspaces, like for a subspace $C \subseteq X$, when do we have $g(\text{closure}_X(C)) = \text{closure}_Y(g(C))$, assuming $C$ & $g(C)$ are homeomorphic?

Btw, do homeomorphisms always restrict to homeomorphisms? Eg in above are $C$ & $g(C)$ homeomorphic (and hence the assumption is redundant)?



Edit to add: Ah wait based on these 2 answers:

Why are the closures of $(0,1)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ not homeomorphic despite the intervals themselves being homeomorphic?

Homeomorphism that maps a closed set to an open set?


It seems
$$g(\text{closure}_X(C)) = \text{closure}_Y(g(C))$$
is always true whether or not $C$ & $g(C)$ are homeomorphic and then
$$A=(0,1), B=(0,\infty), X = Y = \mathbb R, \ \text{then whatever f & g you like}$$
isn't a counter-example because actually no such $f,g$ exist, i.e. there isn't an automorphism $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $f(0,1)= (0,\infty)$

...what's your question, then?

Recall that a function $f$ is continuous on $X$ iff for any $A\subset X$, $f(\overline{A})\subset\overline{f(A)}$ and iff for any $B\subset Y$ \overline{f^{-1}(B)}\susbet f^{-1}(\overline{B})$. See for example, Dugundji's Topology.

Any homeomorphism $f:X \to Y$ induces a homeomorphism $A \to f(A)$ for any subspace $A$ of $X$.

What is an “actual” homeomorphism?

@TedShifrin It's not just that the subspaces are homeomorphic but that the ambient spaces are homeomorphic too.

@BenSteffan Same as previous question but now it's not just that the subspaces are homeomorphic but that the ambient spaces are homeomorphic too.

As a guiding principle, the point of homeomorphisms (of full spaces) is that they preserve everything topologial about those spaces.

@GeoffreyTrang ah right thanks because restriction of continuous is continuous and because $f(A \cap V) = f(A) \cap f(V)$ ( $f(V)$ is open because $V$ is open ) right?

Homeomorphisms always preserve closure of subspaces. If $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, $A\subseteq X, B\subseteq Y$ and $f(A)=B$, then $f(\overline{A})=\overline{B}$. But when I say closure, I mean the closure of $A$ as a subspace of $X$. So if you take $X=A=(0,1)$ then you have to consider the closure of $(0,1)$ as a subspace of $(0,1)$, not as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. And the closure of $(0,1)$ as a subspace of itself is the set $(0,1)$ itself. So your example is not a real counterexample.
Here is one possible way to prove that in the above notations indeed $f(\overline{A})=\overline{B}$. Take $x\in\overline{A}$. We will show that $f(x)\in\overline{B}$. Let $U\subseteq Y$ be an open neighborhood of $f(x)$, we have to show it intersects $B$. By continuity, $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ in $X$, hence it contains some element $a\in A$. But then $f(a)$ is an element of $U\cap B$, so $U$ indeed intersects $B$. This shows that $f(\overline{A})\subseteq\overline{B}$. The other inclusion is symmetric, as $A=f^{-1}(B)$, and $f^{-1}$ is also continuous.
As for the other question, yes, a restriction of a homeomorphism is always a homeomorphism. This is almost immediate from the restriction of a continuous map being continuous.

Right thanks Mark. So indeed there is no such automorphism of $\mathbb R$ that maps either an open bounded interval to an open unbounded interval or a closed bounded interval to a closed unbounded interval right?

@BCLC Why not? $(0,1)$ is indeed homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. What I'm saying is that this doesn't give us a counterexample because as a subspace of $(0,1)$ we have $\overline{(0,1)}=(0,1)$. A bounded closed interval can't be homeomorphic to an unbounded interval, because a closed bounded interval is compact, while an unbounded one is not.

I mean if $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb R$, then your homeomorphism $g: (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ cannot come from $f$ right?

@BCLC If you take an automorphism $f$ of $\mathbb{R}$ and restrict it to $(0,1)$, you will get a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to the image $f((0,1))$. The image will surely not be $\mathbb{R}$, it will be a proper subset.

well so yeah indeed no automorphism of $\mathbb R$ maps an open bounded interval to an open unbounded interval, right?

@BCLC That's right.

Yes, given a homeomorphism $f:X\to Y$, a subset $A\subseteq X$, and its image $B=f(A)\subseteq Y$, we have indeed $$f(\overline A)=\overline B,$$ and here is the simplest proof (imo). It relies on the characterization of $\overline A$ (in $X$) as the smallest closed set containing $A$.
By continuity of $f$, the set $f^{-1}(\overline B)$ is closed. Moreover, it contains
$f^{-1}(B)=A$. Therefore,
$f^{-1}(\overline B)\supseteq\overline A$, i.e. $$\overline B\supseteq f(\overline A).$$
Similarly, by continuity of $g:=f^{-1}$:
$g^{-1}
(\overline A)\supseteq\overline B$, i.e.
$$f
(\overline A)\supseteq\overline B,$$
which ends the proof.
